# Perform Update using Spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

please suggest some way to perform the below query using jdbctemplate.

```
update student set result='pass' where stud_id in (100,101,102);
```

i have tried the below, but stuck with invalid column type.

i am passing the

```
String query = "UPDATE STUDENT SET RESULT = ? WHERE OBJ_ID IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE )";
int[] stud_ids = new int[]{100,101,102};

  getJdbcTemplate().query(updateStateSQL, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
      final Connection con = getJdbcTemplate().getNativeJdbcExtractor().getNativeConnection(ps.getConnection());
      ps.setString(1, 'PASS');
      ps.setArray(2, stud_ids);
    }
  }, new RowMapper<String>() {

    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
      return rs.getString(1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You would use the `update()` method not `query()` method on the JdbcTemplate.

Comment: i have tried with update() as well, but same error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: UPDATE and DELETE cannot be ran with `query()` because they are not querying anything and don't return a result set.  You have to use `update()`.  If you are getting an error, then show the error message and stacktrace.  It will be a LOT easier to help you.  Also, why are you using the more complicated form of query/update that uses a `PreparedStatement`?  You have a crazy simple SQL update command with two parameters, why not use the form that takes a String and a list of parameters?  It would greatly simplify your code.  In fact, why not use `SimpleJdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
String query = "UPDATE STUDENT SET RESULT = ? WHERE OBJ_ID IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE )";

getJdbcTemplate().query(updateStateSQL, ...)
```

You didn't write the value of `updateStateSQL`. If it's the same as `query`, then this cannot work:

```
ps.setString(1, 'PASS');
ps.setArray(2, stud_ids);
```

Because you would need precisely 2 question marks (`?`) in the query and you have only one in your post.

You could try this:

```
String query = "UPDATE STUDENT SET RESULT = ? WHERE OBJ_ID IN ( ? )";
```

But to be honest I've never used `ps.setArray` and I'm not sure it will do what you expect.

What *should* work is using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, something like this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE STUDENT SET RESULT = :result WHERE OBJ_ID IN ( :ids )";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("result", "PASS");
params.put("ids", Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {100, 101, 102}));
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql, params);
```